# HorizontalListView in ICS's gallery. Source?

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Like a lot of people, I'm frustrated that there is no HorizontalListView in android. I'm using an implementation I've found here by Paul, which is great! But not perfect and not work well inside of ScrollView. 
In the new gallery that came with ICS (AOSP by google rom), there is a kind of HorizontalListView, when you choose a photo to show then in the bottom you have all the photos and you can scroll them.

I tried to found the source but with no help!

Does anyone knows where to find the source/this implementation?

Here's the current implementation I use:
http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem after looking in the Android's `Gallery` source.
I've just added the line:

```
getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

In the start of the `onScroll` method.
This just say the parent to stop "taking" this view's touch events, and you get smooth scroll inside of `ScrollView`.

Hope it helped someone.

Comment: please tell me how can i get the Android's gallery source.

Comment: In the question itself I asked for the ICS's Gallery app, not widget. I didn't find the Gallery app source, if that's what your are asking. But if you want the source of the Gallery widget you can find it here: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/ I Hope I've helped you.